# If two first differenced times series are white noise, then what’s the point in finding relationships?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation, differencing

If x’ and y’ are two first differenced time series, I’ve see many analyses where people find a model where y’ is predicted using x’ in some way (lagged or not).

If both x’ and y’ are stationary with no significant autocorrelation, then is finding a model predicting y’ with x’ a silly thing to do? I don’t think I understand here.

Comment: If both $x’$ and $y’$ are stationary with no significant autocorrelation, then it is more likely that any substantial correlation between them (lagged or not) is in some sense meaningful than correlation between $x$ and $y$ would be, since the latter might more easily be spurious

Comment: Thank you. Can you also confirm that the beta coefficient we get using the differenced data can be “interpreted” the same way a coefficient is interpreted when regression is done in levels? I have been told different things by about 7 people now, and there is no literature on this that I can find. It’s driving me insane.

Comment: It seems rather clear to me that if we arrive at coefficient B by regressing x’ and y’, then by simply solving your regression equation for y, you easily see that B also describes the relationship between x and y. Therefore the B we get from x’ and y’ can be interpreted using the original data x and y.

Comment: Related: ["Can I use all estimates in a first differenced regression to apply to levels?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555684).